# Enable HTML-snippets for editing RHTML in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, code-snippets

Is it possible to use Rstudios build in HTML-snippets when editing RHTML-files in Rstudio?

When I open an RHTML-file the language is set to RHTML, as in the picture below:

[image]

- But the HTML-snippets do not work for this language, and I can't see a way to enable RHTML as a language in the snippets menu.
- The HTML-snippets work if I change the language to HTML, instead of RHTML, but then the R-functionality does not work anymore.

Any ideas to get HTML-snippets to work in a RHTML-file in Rstudio?

Using Rstudio Version 1.2.5033

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

Use `<shift> <tab>` to insert HTHL-code snippets in RHTML.

`<tab>` alone does not work, when the language is set to RTML.

This is hinted at here: 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets